# How to keep the first result of a function from Prolog?

Tags: caching, prolog, logic, memoization

I need to write a customized function that will be called many times by other fixed functions. In this function, at the first called time, it will return the total number of lines of a file. The second called time of this function, forward, will return the number of lines in small sections of this file. My question is how I keep the first returned result(total number of lines of a file) and use it for the next called times of my function. I need to write or declare any thing only in this function(not in the caller). Something like this:

```
myFunction(Input, MyResult, FirstResult) :-
   calculateInputFunction(Input, Result),
   !,
   MyResult is Result,
   ... .
```

The problem is, every time myFunction is called, it receives different Input and returns different MyResult. But I would like to keep the first MyResult to use for next called times of myFunction. How can I do that? Thanks very much for your answer in advance.

```
myFunction([V1,V2], Result) :-
  reset,
  cached_all(a(V1,V2)),
  use V1, V2 to calculate Result, 
  ...
  reset,
  finishedCode.
```

The above is my function, there are other functions that will call myFunction by transfering value of V1, V2 to this function and get Result back.

Comment: Actually, I just want to store the first result into this argument and use it for next times.

Comment: Actually, if I can declare a global variable and store the first result into this variable, and use it for next time, it may be one solution but, I don't think use a global variable is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is some form of caching mechanism.  That has to use some global resource somehow.  The dynamic database is usually used for this
purpose.  Here is a very simplistic form of it. More sophisticated techniques in that area are known under the notion of tabling.

```
:- dynamic(cachedgoal_sol/2).

reset :-
   retractall(cachedgoal_sol(_,_)).


eq(A, B) :-
   subsumes_term(A, B),
   subsumes_term(B, A).

cached_call(Goal) :-
   \+ ( cachedgoal_sol(Skel,_), eq(Skel, Goal) ),  % No fitting Goal was cached
   copy_term(Goal, Skel),
      catch(
        (  Goal,
           assertz(cachedgoal_sol(Skel,Goal)),
           fail
        ),
        Pat,
        (reset, throw(Pat))).
cached_call(Goal) :-
   cachedgoal_sol(Skel,XGoal),
    eq(Skel, Goal),
    XGoal = Goal.
```

Usage: Start with `reset.` Then, wrap `Goal` as `cached_call(Goal)`. Don't forget to reset when things change!

Here are some explanations:

`reset/0` just removes all cached results.

`eq/2` is equal up to renaming of variables, provided that the sets of variables of both arguments are disjoint.

`cachedgoal_sol/2` is a dynamic predicate. It is used to store solutions (actually: answers) of a particular goal. To this purpose it keeps a copy of the actual goal in the first argument and the actual answer/solution in the second. Note that for one predicate there might be several, different queries. Say:  `member(X,[a,b,c])` and `member(X,[X1,X2,X3])`. These queries will be handled and cached independently of each other.

If a goal has to be cached anew, a copy of the term is created to have a "key" for the cache. Then, the goal is executed and each answer is stored - this is done exhaustively.  This is particularly interesting for queries that have more than one answer.

Further the goal is protected with `catch/3` catching all errors `Pat`. In this manner, all errors that happen to occur while executing the goal will cause a `reset` of the cache. This is particularly important for non-terminating queries: `cached_call(length(L,N))` would otherwise leave a finite number of solutions in the cache - which would leave the cache in an inconsistent state...

In any case, the first clause **always fails**. So it is here only for the side effect of updating the cache.

The second clause now uses the cache. Note that it is not possible to `XGoal = Goal` "further to the left", because `eq/2` has to ensure that we are using only the results of the very same query.

As I said already: This is a very naive way of doing this, but at least it is simple and relatively robust.

---

As to your original program. You can now write:

```
..., cached_call(calculateInputFunction(Input, Result)), ...
```

every time you need that value.

Comment: Hi false, Thanks very much for your answer.Predicate "cached_call" stores the Goal(first result in my case) from predicate "cachedgoal_sol"(myFunction in this case), doesn't it? First, "cached_call" checks whether the goal is already in database(if it is, it is failed). Skel is a temporary variable to store the goal. What is Pat in this case, I know it is an exception but what does this mean?. Can you help me clarify more about predicates such as eq(A,B), the second "cached_call"? Sorry, I'm new to Prolog, so it's a little bit hard to understand your code.

Comment: I updated my question to show my general code. Thanks very much for your help.