# How to store the first returned value of a function in prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

I have a function like this:

```
myFunction(V1, V2, Result) :-
  Result is V1/V1cover + V2/V2cover,
  write(Result).

myFunction(0,0,0).

keepValue(V1,V2,V1cover,V2cover) :-
  V1cover is V1,
  V2cover is V2.
```

There are other functions that call myFunction many times and get the Result back. However, I would like to get the first Result that myFunction is called first time and keep it to use for calls later(In this case, it is V1cover and V2cover). For example, first time, myFunction(4,4,A) is called. Then it returns A = 2. After that I would like to keep the value of V1cover(4) and V2cover(4) to use for next called times. How I can do that? I tried to apply a cached techonology like and apply it into myFunction:

```
 :- dynamic(cachedGoal_sol/2).

 reset :-
   retractall(cachedGoal_sol(_, _)).

 eq(A, B) :-
   subsumes_term(A, B),
   subsumes_term(B, A).

 cached_call(Goal) :-
   \+ (cachedGoal_sol(First,_), eq(First, Goal)),
   copy_term(Goal, First),
   catch(
   ( Goal,
     assertz(cachedGoal_sol(First, Goal)),
     fail
   ),
   Pat,
   (reset, throw(Pat))).

 cached_call(Goal) :-
   cachedGoal_sol(First, Results),
   eq(First, Goal),
   Results = Goal.

 myFunction(V1, V2, Result) :-
  **cached_call(keepValue(V1,V2,V1cover,V2cover),**
  Result is V1/V1cover + V2/V2cover,
  write(Result).
```

but it doesn't work, when I try to run the second time myFunction(2,3,A) and trace the program, it actually stores solution of the first call but I couldn't get the first values of V1cover, V2cover since eq() in the second cached_call() fails. Is there a way to only get values of V1cover, V2cover without touching to V1,V2 since they are input? Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: Those are not functions and you don't call them. You have predicates and goals you want to satisfy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some errors and it's a bit too complicated. I'll try to give you an answer that might be useful to others too.

**Let's suppose we need a predicate to store information about the context in which a goal was first satisfied.**

I'll use a simple example. Let's say we have a rule to find pairs of numbers between 1 and 4 that add to 6.

```
sum_to_six(X, Y) :- between(1, 4, X), between(1, 4, Y), X + Y =:= 6.
```

Trying to find all pairs that satisfy the above rule, one gets the following answer:

```
?- findall(pair(X,Y), sum_to_six(X, Y), All).
All = [pair(2, 4), pair(3, 3), pair(4, 2)].
```

Now, let's return to your question. Let's suppose we need the first pair that satisfied the goal. We should modify the rule for predicate `sum_to_six/2`.

```
sum_to_six(X, Y):-
        between(1, 4, X), between(1, 4, Y), X + Y =:= 6,
        store_first(pair(X,Y)).
```

The subgoal `store_first(pair(X,Y))` succeeds every time, but asserts `pair(X,Y)` just the first time (if there is no other `pair(_,_)` in the dynamic memory). So, the answer you need might be something similar to this:

```
store_first(Goal):-
        Goal =.. [Name | Args],  %% Name is the name of the predicate
        length(Args, N),         %% N represents its arity
        length(NVars, N),
        Test =.. [Name | NVars], %% Test is a goal like p(_, _, _, ...)
        (
         Test, !
        ;
         assertz(Goal)
        ).
```

Now, to get the stored information:

```
?- retractall(pair(_,_)), findall(_, sum_to_six(_,_), _), pair(FirstX, FirstY).
FirstX = 2,
FirstY = 4.
```

Comment: Hi Tudor, can you please tell me what is Test? what do you mean p(_,_,...)? Morever, where is NVars and why do you need to put length(Nvars,N) between length(Args,N) and Test =..? Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: One question more, if I call sum_to_six(X,Y) many times with different X,Y, does this mean store_first(pair(X,Y)) will store many pairs with the different X,Y? If it does, how to put a condition to store only one Goal for many times of calling sum_to_six(X,Y)?

Comment: So, I expect `Goal` to have to be a first-order structure `p(arg1,arg2,...argn)`. That is one limitation of this implementation, but might be sufficient for you. Then `Name` is p (the name of the predicate) and `Args` is the list of its arguments. We are interested just in finding the arity of p, that is the purpose of putting `length(Args, N)` there. The subgoal `length(NVars,N)` will be satisfied by unifying NVars with a list of unbound variables. Then `Test` is a goal that unifies with any fact similar with Goal. If such a fact does not exist in the memory,  Goal is asserted, otherwise not.

Comment: You can satisfy `sum_to_six(X,Y)` for any number of times. You will have the first pair `X`, `Y` that succeeded. Try this in prolog: `?- sum_to_six(2,4)`, then `sum_to_six(3,3)` and others. Every time you ask for `pair(FirstX, FirstY)` you get `FirstX=2, FirstY=4`.

Comment: Hi Tudor, Sorry for bothering you again. Is there a way to write retractall(pair(,)), findall(, sum_to_six(,_), _), pair(FirstX, FirstY) in sum_to_six()? I get an infinite loop when I put them in sum_to_six(). Because I would like to get value FirstX, FirstY every time I call sum_to_six(), I tried to put them under store_First(), but it doesn't work. Moreover, what is the case if X,Y are inputs of sum_to_six(X,Y). How can I store first value of X,Y, because there are other functions that call sum_to_six with different input and I would like to store the first value of X,Y.

Comment: To access at any time that first pair (X,Y) that satisfied your goal, you just put a subgoal `pair(X, Y)`.

Comment: The part with `retractall ... findalll ... pair(FirstX, FirstY)` is just an example of having the goal `sum_to_six(X,Y)` satisfied a couple of times, and in the end having a fact `pair(FirstX, FirstY)` in memory corresponding to the first pair that succeeded.

Comment: We can [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55270/prolog) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the first answer, simply write

```
..., cached_call(once(Goal)), ....
```

using [this definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040898/how-to-keep-the-first-result-of-a-function-from-prolog/24042110#24042110).